# Search country names with JavaScript and display country details

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, api, element

In my project I want to get a country flag while searching, with an API call, and on clicking on that flag it should redirect to another page and display the respective country details.

I tried with a JavaScript API call, in that I am getting the country details and the flag on the same page after clicking on search, but I want to display details other than flags in another page. After clicking on the flag I want to display the country details.

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#display").empty();
  let name =  e.currentTarget.name.value;
  if(!name){

    alert("Enter name");

    return;
  }
  getCountryName(name).then(result =>{
    result.forEach(element => {
      var card = $('<div>', {class: "card"}).appendTo('#display');
      var country = $('<div>', {class: "country-info"}).appendTo(card);

      var img = $('<a href="https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${name}"><div>', 
        {class: "img"}).appendTo(country);
      $('<img>', {src: element.flag}).appendTo(img);
      var text = $('<div>', {class: "right-text"}).appendTo(country);
      $('<p>', {text: "Name: " + element.name}).appendTo(text);
      $('<p>', {text: "Top Level Domain: " + 
      element.topLevelDomain}).appendTo(text);
      $('<p>', {text: "Capital: " + element.capital}).appendTo(text);
      $('<h4>', {text: 'Currencies:'}).appendTo(text);
      element.currencies.forEach(element =>{
        var currencies = $('<div>', {
          class: "currencies"
        }).appendTo(text);
        $('<span>', {text: element.code + " "}).appendTo(currencies);
      })
    });

  }).catch(err =>console.log(err));
});

async function getCountries(){
  const response = await 
  fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all`);
  const responseData = await response.json();

  return responseData;
}

async function getCountryName(name){
  const response = await 
  fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${name}`);
  const responseData = await response.json();

  return responseData;
}
```

```html
 

 <html lang="en" >
  <head>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   
   </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="search-group ">
      <label for="name">Enter country</label>
      <input class="search-line" type="search" name="name">
      <br/>
      <input class="search-line" type="submit" id="search" value="Search 
      by Name">
    </div>
  </form>

   <div id="display" class="search-line"></div>
  </div>
```

I want to get the country details in another page after clicking on a country       flag. Now i am getting the country details and flags on the same page.

Comment: Please any one give me suggestion ,how to get expected result

Comment: How /where are you navigating to the new page?

Answer (score 0):

You already got all details with one call, you can hide the details and just bind an onClick event to the image by clicking on it, show the details and hide the flag. I just added some css and a javascript function to handle that, and if you want to redirect to another page and show the details there, simply add another page and pass down the details and show there. check out the changes I made below

```
<html lang="en" >
 <head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256 CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>
 <style media="screen">
  .right-text {
    display: none;
   }
 </style>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <form>
    <div class="search-group ">
     <label for="name">Enter country</label>
     <input class="search-line" type="search" name="name">
     <br/>
     <input class="search-line" type="submit" id="search" value="Search
   by Name">
  </div>
 </form>

  <div id="display" class="search-line"></div>
 </div>

 <script src="main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

and your main.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#display").empty();
   let name =  e.currentTarget.name.value;
   if(!name){
    alert("Enter name");
    return;
   }
   getCountryFlag(name).then(result =>{
    console.log(result[0].flag);
    result.forEach(element => {
    var card = $('<div>', {class: "card"}).appendTo('#display');
    var country = $('<div>', {class: "country-info"}).appendTo(card);

    var img = $('<a id="img-link" href="#" onClick="showInfo()"><div>',
      {class: "img"}).appendTo(country);
    $('<img>', {src: element.flag}).appendTo(img);
    var text = $('<div>', {class: "right-text"}).appendTo(country);
    $('<p>', {text: "Name: " + element.name}).appendTo(text);
    $('<p>', {text: "Top Level Domain: " +
    element.topLevelDomain}).appendTo(text);
    $('<p>', {text: "Capital: " + element.capital}).appendTo(text);
    $('<h4>', {text: 'Currencies:'}).appendTo(text);
    element.currencies.forEach(element =>{
      var currencies = $('<div>', {
        class: "currencies"
      }).appendTo(text);
      $('<span>', {text: element.code + " "}).appendTo(currencies);
    })
  });

  }).catch(err =>console.log(err));
 });
});

async function getCountryFlag(name){
  const response = await
  fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${name}`);
  const responseData = await response.json();

  return responseData;
}

function showInfo() {
  console.log($('.right-text'));
  $('.right-text').css('display', 'block');
  $('img').css('display', 'none');
}
```

Comment: Thank you .but is it possible to display that country info in another html page